# How to override the global listeners being pushed in batchJS from other plugins in Jira?

Tags: javascript, jira, jira-plugin

We have a custom plugin that is facing some delay due to script of other plugin being injected in the batchJS. Upon checking we have found that the issue is coming from the global listener being triggered from that piece of script.

We tried window.onclick = null but that did not seem to have any effect.

We couldn't use removeListener as we do not have the name of the handler which is triggering the global listener.

Can anyone please suggest what can be done to remove the global listener or to restrict it from being triggered on our screen?

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: Also posted [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/How-to-override-the-global-listeners-being-pushed-in-batchJS/qaq-p/2327881) yesterday.